# Delta Index in Sphinx not always gets updated 100%

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I setup Sphinx for a project a couple of months ago. So far it has worked flawlessly, but lately we have been indexing more sites than before so the updated for the delta index some times are bigger than before and for some reason this is causing the delta index not to update the full index.
We have a MySql DB for the storage, and we implemented a MySQL check with a Time Stamp for the Updates. We have also created a Trigger so every time a record gest updated, it updates the Time Stamp.

Here is the Sphinx.conf
I was wondering if anyone could give some insight were the problem could it.

Best Regards!

```
source main_index
    {
    type                    = mysql

    sql_host                = host
    sql_user                = xxxxxx
    sql_pass                = xxxxxx
    sql_db                  = xxxxxx
    sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query_pre        = SET @maxts := (SELECT NOW())
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query            = SELECT Id, Id id_st,Link,date_added1,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added2,country,source,sec, title, description FROM Sites WHERE ts < @maxts

    sql_query_post       = REPLACE INTO sphinxcounters VALUES ('Sites_tmp', @maxts)

    sql_query_post_index = DELETE FROM sphinxcounters WHERE tablename = 'Sites'

    sql_query_post_index = UPDATE sphinxcounters SET tablename = 'Sites' WHERE tablename = 'Sites_tmp'

    sql_query_post_index = DELETE FROM sphinxklist WHERE ts < (SELECT maxts FROM sphinxcounters WHERE tablename = 'Sites')

    sql_field_string        = description
    sql_field_string        = title
    sql_attr_string         = country
    sql_attr_string         = source
    sql_attr_string         = Link
    sql_attr_string         = sec
    sql_attr_uint           = id_st
    sql_attr_string         = date_added1
    sql_attr_timestamp      = date_added2


    # Index attributes declaration ...
}

source delta_index : main_index
{

    sql_query_pre        = SET @maxts:= (SELECT maxts FROM sphinxcounters WHERE tablename='Sites')
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query            = SELECT Id, Id id_st,Link,date_added1,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added2,country,source,sec, title, description FROM Sites WHERE ts < @maxts

    # Killlist : List of id's in the main index result set that we want to suppress.
    # In the following query we suppress deleted and updated rows from main index

    sql_query_killlist   = SELECT Id FROM Sites WHERE ts >= @maxts UNION SELECT id FROM sphinxklist

}
```

Comment: Is that the correct sql_query in the delta? It has two WHERE? ... how do you sync updates of the delta and main, Can the delta ever be older than main? (eg when regenerate the main, should imiately regen the delta - and it could then be empty)

Comment: Im sorry, the query was wrong on the example, its fine on my actual config. I just updated the example. 
About your question the delta could bring rows that were added to the main at some point, but were updated later on.